# Javascript contentEditable, prevent <br> when there is no text

Tags: javascript

So I have a basic contentEditable div. The problem is that if the user deletes all the text, it actually forms a `<br>` tag inside of the contentEditable. I do not want this `<br>` tag to exist. Is there anyway to prevent this tag from appearing when all of the of the text is deleted?

Thanks

Comment: are there any code examples?

Comment: Just remove it programmatically when saved. If `<br>` is all that exists, remove it.

Comment: Can you please post your code. I created jsbin http://jsbin.com/mopenimoqo/edit?html,css,output which do not contains <br> tag after deleting all content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After stumbling upon [this bugzilla thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1098151), I did a quick little test.

It appears that the `<br>` tags is inserted because you're setting a `<div>` (block) as contentEditable. I think it's automagically inserted to prevent the element from collapsing.

If you do the same thing with a `<span>` (inline) element, CSS-stylized with a

`display: block;
 min-height: xxx px; // To prevent collapsing when empty`

then you're set, no more `<br>` inserted, and the element won't collapse.

[Link to the demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tambbegn/)

PS: I did check only under Firefox. If I remember correctly, there was a [bug on the old WebKit engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488809/how-to-place-caret-inside-an-empty-dom-element-node) where you couldn't place the caret in an empty node, you might encounter it.